# How to efficiently multiply each element of vector with matrix getting enlarged matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I would like to achieve the following in an efficient way in numpy. Suppose I have a matrix

```
A = np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

and

```
B = np.asarray([1, 10, 100])
```

I would like to multiply each element in `A` with the first element of `B`, then each element in `A` with the second element in `B` etc. At the end a matrix of shape `(A.shape[0]*B.shape[0], A.shape[1])`

the result should be

```
np.asarray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [10, 20], [30, 40], [100, 200], [300, 400]])
Out[216]: 
array([[  1,   2],
       [  3,   4],
       [ 10,  20],
       [ 30,  40],
       [100, 200],
       [300, 400]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape with numpy broadcasting:

```
# option 1
(A * B[:,None,None]).reshape(-1, A.shape[1])

#array([[  1,   2],
#       [  3,   4],
#       [ 10,  20],
#       [ 30,  40],
#       [100, 200],
#       [300, 400]])

# option 2
(A.ravel() * B[:,None]).reshape(-1, A.shape[1])

#array([[  1,   2],
#       [  3,   4],
#       [ 10,  20],
#       [ 30,  40],
#       [100, 200],
#       [300, 400]])
```

Or use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,k->kij', A, B).reshape(-1, A.shape[1])
#array([[  1,   2],
#       [  3,   4],
#       [ 10,  20],
#       [ 30,  40],
#       [100, 200],
#       [300, 400]])
```